# Error when checking : expected input to have shape [null,300,300,3] but got array with shape [1,300,300,4]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I'm using [tfjs-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-node) for loading model and predicting results in my Node.js application. It was providing decent results but for some image, the following error was shown:

```
Error when checking : expected input to have shape [null,300,300,3] but got array with shape [1,300,300,4].
```

Code for loading and predicting results:

```js
const loadModel = async (imagePath) => {
  const image = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
  let tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(image);

  const resizedImage = tensor.resizeNearestNeighbor([300, 300]);
  const batchedImage = resizedImage.expandDims(0);
  const input = batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255));

  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
    process.env.ML_MODEL_PATH || "file://./ml-model/model.json"
  );

  let predictions = await model.predict(input).data();
  predictions = Array.from(predictions);
};
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
let tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(image, 3);
```

it will remove alpha if the image is allowed to have transparency like png.

[Tensorflow documentation source.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_png)

Another possibility is that you had CMYK image. For which I wouldn't know the answer, except that you may try to convert to RGB.